# How to serve static content in Mono Apache MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, apache, jquery-ui, jqgrid, mono

ASP.NET MVC application Page contains order header and order rows.
jquery, jqgrid, jqueru ui and some jqueru ui plugins are used.
All js files are compiled to single minified file default.js

Resources are loaded from ASP.NET standard Scripts, Content and themes subdirectories
in ASP .NET MVC application tree.

Running Audits in Chrome browser raises recommends to make static resources cacheable and without cookies.

For first audit issue It looks like Mono disables cache control. Response header looks like:

```
Cache-Control:private
Connection:Keep-Alive
Date:Sun, 07 Oct 2012 19:38:15 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=97
Server:Apache
```

For second issue it looks like browser sends cookies for css files and images:

```
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=8E6FF8F8BAE86246BF49C1C5; .MyAuth=fDmFg9sG5ZfQBCwcgOpdrgSH/OcY5+xVyL9XJko1SwObAZcMQbZyNYz4JZ7fTZLBNVhjw23LuKrBiYqM5G0lccXUxkK/S37rToQfmBR4JfmlVTBT; .MyRoles=
```

How to fix those issues ?
It would be best to keep ASP.NET application directory stucture and serve all files from application subdirectories

Chrome audit results are:

```
Leverage browser caching (16)
The following resources are explicitly non-cacheable. Consider making them cacheable if possible:

Detail
jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css
ui.jqgrid.css
Site.css
default.js
ui-bg_inset-hard_100_fcfdfd_1x100.png
ui-bg_flat_55_fbec88_40x100.png
ui-bg_glass_95_fef1ec_1x400.png
ui-bg_gloss-wave_55_5c9ccc_500x100.png
DokG.png
ui-bg_inset-hard_100_f5f8f9_1x100.png
ui-bg_glass_85_dfeffc_1x400.png
ui-icons_6da8d5_256x240.png
ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png
ui-icons_d8e7f3_256x240.png
ui-icons_469bdd_256x240.png

Serve static content from a cookieless domain (14)
2.53KB of cookies were sent with the following static resources. Serve these static resources from a domain that does not set cookies:

jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css
ui.jqgrid.css
Site.css
ui-bg_inset-hard_100_fcfdfd_1x100.png
ui-bg_flat_55_fbec88_40x100.png
ui-bg_glass_95_fef1ec_1x400.png
ui-bg_gloss-wave_55_5c9ccc_500x100.png
DokG.png
ui-bg_inset-hard_100_f5f8f9_1x100.png
ui-bg_glass_85_dfeffc_1x400.png
ui-icons_6da8d5_256x240.png
ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png
ui-icons_d8e7f3_256x240.png
ui-icons_469bdd_256x240.png
```